# How to interpolate tmux variable in .tmux.conf?

Tags: tmux

How to interpolate a variable that was created inside `.tmux.conf` to be used for a longer command?

I have this in `.tmux.conf`:

```
# show window name if set by user
WINDOW_NAME='#{?#{==:#{window_name},#{pane_current_command}},#{pane_current_command},[#{window_name}]:#{pane_current_command}}'

set -g window-status-format $WINDOW_NAME
set -g window-status-current-format $WINDOW_NAME
```

Now this works fine, as in it shows the window status plus the current window name, but I would like to interpolate this variable something like this:

`set -g window-status-format '$WINDOW_NAME > #{=21:pane_title}'`

however it does not work, and instead of interpreting the variable it just shows `$WINDOW_NAME > user@ip-10...`

Assuming the current command was `ssh` the expected result would be `ssh > user@ip-10...`

Comment: Have you tried double quotes?